# What is the difference between "use-directed" and "use-driven"(in the instantiation mechanism)?

Tags: c++, templates

Recently i have been reading the book "Inside the C++ Object Model". In chapter 7.1, section "Member Function Instantiation", the author writes that the original intent of C++'s support for template can be inferred as a "use-directed automatic instantiation mechanism". In the same paragraph, he provides another concept, "use-driven automatic instantiation mechanism"(sorry that i can't provide the exact page number, since i am reading a translated version of the book).

My question is, what is the difference between these two concepts/terms, "use-directed" and "use-driven" in this context(template instantiation mechanism), as well as, even in a much more broader range when not just restricted to this context?

---

### update

I've found the original text about this topic. Page 168 of the below PDF.
https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/1604/89e8b12cd9a44cbff0cd85fb6aa05437d1ac.pdf

Comment: on the way to the coffee machine I am "coffee-directed" on the way back I am "coffee-driven". Doesnt the author explain the concepts? I doubt that there is lots of insight to be found in those terms. Maybe the author just likes to talk some mumbo jumbo

Comment: I can understand on the way to the coffee machine is "coffee-directed", but "coffee-driven" still confuse me.

Comment: well, the distinction doesnt really make much sense, you could say as well that on the way to the coffee machine you are "coffee-driven" (coffee is my motivation to walk to the machine). Maybe the author made a typo and actually meant exactly the same in both cases

Comment: This book is from *one thousand nine hundred ninety bloody six*. Recycle it. It is hopelessly outdated.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's asking about very specific choice of terms in a book that's unlikely to be of help to a broader audience. Especially since the author's choice between these two terms may be unintentional to begin with.

Comment: @n.m. actually I think in the year 2018 it does matter even less than it did in 1996 what was once the original intent of template support in C++ ;)